# Django Project goes wrong when using non-hardcode url match

Tags: python, django

Here's two apps in my django project named "users" and "experiments". In a template of "users" I was trying to use:

```
<a href="{% url 'experiments:1' %}">list</a>
```

I was hoping that this would lead to the url 'experiments/1', but a NoReverseMatch problem was raised.

Here's the url configuration in experiments/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'experiments'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:experimentId>', views.showExperiments, name='showExperiments'),
    ]
```

I'm a fresh learning django and I've tried so hard but failed to figure this out. I don't know how to use this url reverse match when it's related to regex.

And here's my view for that url:

```
def showExperiments(request, experimentId=0):
    if(experimentId != 0):
        experiment = Experiment.Objects.filter(experimentId=experimentId)

        return render(request, 'experiment/showExperiments.html', {
            'experimentName': experiment.experimentName,
            'experimentContent': experimentContent,
            'experiments': Experiment.Objects.all(),
            })
    else: 
        return render(request, 'experiment/showExperiments.html', {'experiments': Experiment.Objects.all()})
```

By the way, the version of django is 2.0.

Comment: Try to change the line `path('<int:experimentId>', views.showExperiments, name='showExperiments'),` with this one `url(r'^experiments/(?P<pk>\d+)',views. showExperiments, name='showExperiments'),` also in your a html tag add this on `href="{% url 'showExperiments:1' %}"`

Comment: can you show the view function for that url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'experiments:showExperiments' 1 %}">list</a>
```

use this in your template

Comment: Oh it worked! So from this answer I am wondering that, if in this kind of url reverse, the word after colon refers to a function name in views instead of the name defined in the urls.py? I may get this wrong all the time...

Comment: no the name after the colon is the name that you have used for that particular url in the urls.py

Comment: I've been got these concepts all tangled together. Thanks so much for helping me figure this out.